# How can I find out the variable name in python?

Tags: python, interface

I know how I can find out the python command by clicking a button in the Blender interface, and then look in the *info* window:
[image]

For example, as can be seen, I added a cube, UV sphere, plane, camera, lamp, pressed <kbd>A</kbd> twice.

But how can I find out an object variable name, for example the y-rotation of an object. Because I can't find the y-rotation, when I point my mouse over it, I can only find the rotation:
[image]

Comment: Rotation is a vector, for Eulers (x, y, z).  rotation_euler[1] or  rotation_euler.y is the y rotation component.

Comment: the name of the objects as set in the "outliner" are the names of the objects. type  `bpy.data.objects.items()` to see all current objects and their names

Comment: Does this addon help? https://github.com/adhihargo/display_matrix

Answer (score 2):

This has been turned off by default in 2.80. Turn it back on in Edit > Preferences > Interface > Display > Python Tooltips