# Python code for EDIT Mode, Mesh -> Separate -> By Loose Parts

Tags: python, mesh

Python code doesn't appear, Edit mode, Mesh--> Separate --> By loose parts
It physically separate objects but no Python code appeared in INFO.

Comment: Can confirm same behaviour in 2.91 alpha.  The operator call is `bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type='LOOSE')`  Consider filing a bug report.

Comment: just need to enable python tooltips: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69762/how-can-i-find-out-the-variable-name-in-python